# Is there a way to choose the names of the evolutions file in Play?

Tags: playframework, playframework-evolutions

I'm using the evolutions from Play! (2.5) and since my project is growing I'm ending with a 23.sql file (after 22 n.sql files in my evolutions conf folder).

It begins to be difficult to retrieve informations.

Is there a way to name these files differently, as, for example addEventTable.sql instead of 24.sql?

Answer (score 0):

Currently not using the default evolutions mechanism. But you can use something like [flyway-play](https://github.com/flyway/flyway-play) which enables you to have evolutions file named like `V1__Create_person_table.sql`, `V2__Add_people.sql`, etc.